# Android - XML Layout - HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello Friends I have just started learning android by watch videos by Travis.

He has made and app having an Image slider in it. I followed each and every step and everything is working fine. He has used

Below is my XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/IVDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/a"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/setBG"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/set_as_wallpaper" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/viewImage1"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/a" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/viewImage2"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/c" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/viewImage3"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/d" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/viewImage4"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/e" />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Images are displaying right...but at a time there can be only 1 and a half image can be displayed...while there are many other images ...so there I am using HorizontalScrollView to show a slider to slide the images.

This is the video which I referred http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wp5sORsPopw

Comment: Can you give more detail about the error it gave you? Also, are you sure that you have the corresponding drawables that you refer to in the `ImageView`s.

Comment: Its not giving any error except warning for ImageView to add description...And yeah all the drawables are there...The only problem I am facing is that there is not scroller there to scroll images.

Comment: @Shivam I have posted solution try this it might help you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set horizontal scrollview width `android:layout_width="200dp"` So to solve you problem replace it to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`.

Like this : -

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  <<SET it to wrap_content like
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >
```

**To show the scrollbar in horizontal scrollview.**

Write this in layout file where you define horizontal scrollview.

```
android:fadeScrollbars="false" which is equivalent to ScrollView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

As you are saying I don't think there is any problem in it. Its working fine. I have checked in emulator. Images are sliding horizontally fine!!

Comment: Sorry but its still not showing the scroller..Please paste the above code in a new xml file . and add any images by the name of a , c, d, e ..The problem is I am not getting the scroller in the graphical layout as well as the emulator.

Comment: @Shivam Now your images are displaying complete right. Now you want to show the scroll bar in scrollview.??

Comment: Yeah right so that those images which were going out of the box can be shown and selected with the help of a scrollview

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood what is your question normally, But as I understood you must `Clean` your project , go to `Project` (in menuBar) -> `Clean...` than choose your project and clean , it must help.

EDIT:
here is the problem

```
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

You must change this code to this one

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
```

Also wrap_content means that the view wants to be just big enough to enclose its content, So it must be the problem

Regards

Comment: Nahh its not related to cleaning...My main question is that when I am using <HorizonalScrollView a scroller is not getting displayed there for the images

Comment: Nopes, Images are displaying right...but at a time there can be only 1 and a half image can be displayed...while there are many other images ...so there I am using <HorizontalScrollView to show a slider to slide the images. Hope I am clear this time.

Comment: I am sorry bro but its still now working. Actually its not related to images size . The main problem I am facing is that the scroll bar is not getting displayed which will let me slide through all the images which are going out of screen right now.

Comment: Can you please give the link of the tutorial of Travis that you sad?

Comment: as I saw the different only these two rows in horizontalScrollView


    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"

So try to delete them , maybe will help , I don't know

Comment: I did...Maybe eclipse changed that automatically but I deleted them and still same problem...Can you try this code by making a new xml and pasting it there and checkout what the problem might be because I have been working on it for more than 6 hours now.

Comment: Tell the truth I'm working now , and don't have any more time.

Comment: Ok no probs buddy...thanx for helping as much as you could have...thanks a lot. :) will reply back here if I will come up with some solution.

Comment: Ok bro :) , If I found some time , I'll try to help again ;)

Comment: It worked...just tried it on emulator and its working...thanx bro :)